# Magento 2: Cookie issue

Tags: magento2

I am using it in my code to get the cookie in a simple PHP way. But need to get in Magento 2 standard format.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['getCookie'])){
     .................
}
```

How to get in Magento standard format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use in a php file the cookieManager

```
protected $_cookieManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
)
{
    $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
}
```

You can get the cookie with :

```
$cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie("CookieName");
```

You can delete a cookie with :

```
$this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie(
                "CookieName"
            );
```